# Linux 'cp' copies symlink instead of target file

Tags: linux, symlink, cp

In my directory I have 2 files: a text file and a symbolic link to that text file.

```
base_v21.txt -> base_v001.txt
base_v001.txt
```

When I try to copy `base_v001.txt` using the following command:

```
# cp base_v001.txt /targetdir
```

Instead of `base_v001.txt` getting copied, `base_v21.txt` is copied.

```
# ls /targetdir
base_v21.txt
```

So even though I specify the file I want to copy by the full filename the symbolic link gets copied instead.

I've seen posts about using `-L` or `-H` to dereference symlinks, but that doesn't really apply to my situation, because I'm trying to copy the target file itself; not the symlink.

As for why the symlink and the target file are in the same directory, I have no control over that.

Comment: You shuold edit your question to make it understandable. Check the "base" names....

Comment: giving the output of `ls -l` instead of only `ls` would make things more clear for all the answerers

Comment: Show the command that you used to create the symbolic link and also correct the filenames (you reference a filename that is `base_v21.txt` in the text, but not in the commands).

Comment: `cp base_v001.txt /targetdir` produces `/targetdir/base_v21.txt`? Are you absolutely sure? There's no way for the system to know what symlinks are pointing to that file. I would understand this if you used the symlink as the copy source and got the name from the symlink destination instead, or something like that.

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes, I understand it's a odd result. I've searched the web for a similar occurrence, but so far have not seen any. It forced me to make an account and post this question.

Comment: You question is confusing: show the commands that you ran. Don't do it from memory. Do it and show it. If you do this, you will know what you did. You will then discover that you did not do what you say you did. You will then discover the problem.

Comment: Maybe the file was already there, and the `cp` did nothing.

Comment: I closed the question as unclear as the the details of what seems to be happening are unclear. How the symbolic link is created is unclear, as is the file type of the file at the destinaton, whether it existed before, etc. A full verbatim transcript showing the initial file, the creation of the link, and the copy command, would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

let the destination be `/tmp/`

If you want to copy the target file but not the `symlink`, :

```
readlink -ne base.txt | xargs -0 cp -t /tmp/
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to get the target of the symlink is to use the `-L` option:

> -L, --dereference
> always follow symbolic links in SOURCE

this command achieves your aim:

```bsh
cp -L base_v001.txt /targetdir
```

Comment: The problem seems to be that `base_v001.txt` isn't even a link in there, so there's no link to (not) follow...

Answer (score 2):

Copying to a directory creates a new file with the same name as the source file in the target directory, if a new file name is not given. So the following commands will give the same output:

```
> cp base_v21.txt /targetdir
> cp base_v21.txt /targetdir/base_v21.txt
```

These create a new file called "base_v21.txt" with the contents of the file in the source directory. In this case, these are the contents of "base_v001.txt" because of the symbolic link. Essentially, you are doing the following:

```
> cat base_v21.txt >> /targetdir/base_v21.txt
```

Thus it is to be expected that the following commands give the same result after copying:

```
> cat base_v21.txt
> cat base_v001.txt
> cat /targetdir/base_v21.txt
```

You can see that this occurs with either a hard link or symbolic link in the following examples:

```
> touch base_v001.txt
> ln -s base_v001.txt base_v21.txt #create soft link
> cat "test" >> base_v001.txt
> mkdir dir
> cd dir
> cp ../base_v21.txt .
> ls
base_v21.txt

>cat base_v21.txt
test

> ln base_v001.txt base_v21.txt #create hard link
> cat "test" >> base_v001.txt
> mkdir dir
> cd dir
> cp ../base_v21.txt .
> ls
base_v21.txt

>cat base_v21.txt
test
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, that is a very strange behavior.

Check and see what conflicting arguments (if any) are aliased to the `cp` command.
To do this, run the [`type`](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/typeh.html) command. (i.e. `type cp`)

Other than that, you can try to perform your operation with an alternative utility such as [`rsync`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) which also has support for handling symlinks (with the arguments `--links` `--copy-links` and `--hard-links`)

Comment: It seems the OP describes a situation in which running the command `cp base_v001.txt /targetdir` returns with the file (symbolic link) named `/targetdir/base_v21.txt`. You don't find that strange?

Comment: Wait, I read the file names wrong. The way it's actually written is so weird I must have mentally blocked the idea, or something... Sorry.